# Parity Trace Issue: TraceDB resync required

Tags: parity, json-rpc, evm, nodes

I am trying to use the trace functionality included in the parity node (https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-trace-module) but I am having trouble configuring my node.

I have tried to run my parity node using

```
parity --tracing on --pruning archive
```

But I get the following issue:

```
TraceDB resync required
```

I have tried to reset my database by doing `parity db kill` and rerunning the first command but I get the same issue. Can anyone help me set up the TraceDB?

I am running parity through home-brew, version v1.8.2-beta

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a minor annoyance, `parity db kill` does not reset your user defaults. Have a look at this:

```
 $ cat ~/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/chains/ethereum/user_defaults 
 {"fat_db":false,"is_first_launch":false,"mode":"active","pruning":"fast","tracing":false}
```

Editing this file to read `"tracing":true` will solve your issue.

Comment: Thx! We synced node 2 weeks, and we can't resync again!

Answer (score 1):

I found a sort of solution, if you specify the db location (using `--base-path`) then it works. I think the `parity db kill` is not deleting an existing database of mine that I cannot find

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten past this particular issue by removing the chain and re-sync'ing.

In my case, when I start up parity, I see:

```
2018-08-18 06:56:57  Starting Parity-Ethereum/v2.1.0-nightly-a6ce0fe57-20180818/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.28.0
2018-08-18 06:56:57  Keys path /home/[user]/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/keys/[chain]
2018-08-18 06:56:57  DB path /home/[user]/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/chains/[chain]/db/471758401ece60a9
```

To get past the problem, I deleted all traces and started over again:

```
rm -rf /home/[user]/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/keys/[chain]
rm -rf /home/[user]/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/chains/[chain]
```

I don't think you need to remove the keys -- simply removing the chain db should be enough:

```
rm -rf /home/[user]/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/chains/[chain]/db
```

Obviously, you'll have to edit that to  point to the parity chain db in your on environment.  It may be as simple as replacing [user] with the user that runs parity and [chain] with the chain.  It might not be located within your user account at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a testing blockchain you can just delete the cache and chains folder. Editing the file user_defaults to read "tracing":true did not solve the issue for me.